# How to get number of inputs from a form

Tags: python, forms, post

In python appengine, I need to determine the number of input boxes that are received into the post method. It will be a variable number known to the get method, but I don't know how to pass that number to the post method. All will have code generated names `'ans'+str(k)` where `k` is an integer. I get the first one by calling:

`self.request.get('ans0')`

So, how can I determine the number of these guys in my `def post(self):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
len(self.request.arguments())
```

Comment: @user1680980 If that actually helped you.. you should accept the answer as the correct one.. (little check mark under the vote count)

Comment: sorry that check mark did not show on my tablet, but now I see it.